# AWS Cluster with Cloudera Manager: Cannot create AMI's

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudera, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

I run AWS cluster with Cloudera Manager.
I'd like to create AMI from one of cluster instances.

The problem is: creation of AMI is not available for any cluster's instance.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that Cloudera Manager uses `instance-store` AMIs and creating images is only possible for EBS-based AMI instances, not for instance-store images, which boot from local and ephemeral storage.

Bundling and AMI image from the console is only possible for Windows instances that are also of instance-store type.